# How can i change year with LocalDate by adding weeks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localdate

Here is my code. This method works only for 1 ( current year). When week number is more than 53, dates start from dates in first week in current year but not the next.
Year has 52 or 53 weeks, so when week is last (52or53) i have 2020-12-28 - 2021-01-03, but when I want get first week of next year (2021-01-04 - 2021-01-10) it outputs me first week from 2020 ( 2019-12-30 - 2020-01-05).

```
public void showPreviousNextWeekDays(DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper, long weekChange) {
        if (weekChange >= 0) {
            LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(weekChange);

            final long weekNumber = ld.get(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR); //takes week from current date 



             LocalDate firstDayOfWeek = ld.ofYearDay(ld.getYear(), (int)weekNumber)
                     .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber)
                     .with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);


            LocalDate lastDayOfWeek = ld.ofYearDay(ld.getYear(), (int)weekNumber)
                    .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber)
                    .with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);


            String firstAndLastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.toString() + " - " + lastDayOfWeek.toString();
            daysArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DayModel>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.NextWeek(weekChange));
            daysList.setAdapter(daysArrayAdapter);
```

How can i go forward with years also by adding weeks?

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you, i have added all information. I think problem is in methods which i use for firstDayOfWeek and LastDayOfWeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your code is not correct. When I set `weekChange` to 14 and run today (September 29), I get `2019-12-30 - 2020-01-05` where expected result would be `2021-01-04 - 2020-01-10`. Also for 15 and 16 weeks your code goes back to a week in the beginning of this year rather than finding a week in the beginning of next year as it should.

I suggest the following, which is also a bit simpler:

```
    int weekChange = 14;

    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusWeeks(weekChange);
    LocalDate firstDayOfWeek = ld.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
    LocalDate lastDayOfWeek = ld.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);

    String firstAndLastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.toString() + " - " + lastDayOfWeek.toString();

    System.out.println(firstAndLastDayOfWeek);
```

Output when run today:

> 2021-01-04 - 2021-01-10

`LocalDate` uses the ISO calendar system including ISO weeks if not explicitly instructed otherwise. So we can be sure that `ld.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)` gives us Monday at the start of the same ISO week. Similarly `ld.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)` gives us Sunday at the end of the ISO week. So there is nothing more to it.

### What happened in your code?

Sticking to the case of `weekChange` 14 and running today.

`ld` becomes 2021-01-05 (Tuesday 14 weeks from now). This date is in week 1 of 2021, so `weekNumber` will be 1.

`ofYearDay` is a *static* method of `LocalDate`. So `ld.ofYearDay(ld.getYear(), (int)weekNumber)` gives you the same date as you would have got from `LocalDate.ofYearDay(ld.getYear(), (int)weekNumber)`. It does not use `ld` for anything. Since `weekNumber` is 1, you get day 1 of 2021, so `2021-01-01`. Passing the week number as the day of year to `ofYearDay()` is meaningless. 2021-01-01 happens to fall in week 53 of 2020. So `with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, weekNumber)` adjusts the date back to week 1 of 2020. This is where we go a year wrong. The result is 2020-01-03. The Monday of that week is 2019-12-30, which explains why you got this as the first day of week in the output.

The last day of week is similar. And week numbers 2 and 3 are similar since you use the week number as a day of year, and January 2 and 3 fall in the last week of the previous year, 2020, too.

How did I find out? I ran your code in my debugger. There it was clear to see. If you haven’t yet learned to use a debugger. I suggest that now is the best of all times.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me a lot. I have used debuger but can not figure out how can i change my code to make it correct . I've also learn something new so thank you again.